# Changing something in a view depending on the sequence of activities

Tags: java, android

Is it possible to change something in a view depending on the sequence of activities? For example, in an adapter I would like to highlight a text, corresponding to an element clicked in a list of elements of a previous activity. But this, only if this adapter is the result of a sequence of certain activities, given that it is used in a fragment, hosted by an activity that can in turn be called up by one of two other activities.

Comment: Please put your code and ask your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep history of every activity opened by keeping a list/stack of ids (integer or string). First activity that starts in your app will make a new empty list and record itself into it. When another activity is opened you pass that list in the intent. Next Activity extracts the list and adds its own id in it then passes it to next Activity in intent. This way, any activity will have a history of all activities opened previously.

If you want to send additional information along with ids you can make a Parcelable class and pass that along.